# D3.JS Pie chart animation Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

I have been working on this pie chart transition : https://bl.ocks.org/SpaceActuary/97d70de639c9c1724f434a9c64cc1a68

I am trying to get it to angular. It returns undefined from here:

```
      let outerRad0 = this.radiusScale(d3.sum(data0));
      let outerRad1 = this.radiusScale(d3.sum(data1));
```

I tried several hours but I can't figure out missing part here.

Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v3qd47

Comment: hey, you are trying to `literally` use the library as is in your code. also, your stackblitz `app.module.ts` seems to have no import for the d3 module. you might want to use an angular implementation of the same or stick to regular javascript as shown in the example.

Comment: If it is an import error it should throw an import error. This is not an import error I think

Comment: https://ibb.co/hZJtM0S - this is from the stackblitz you provided.

Comment: https://ibb.co/VjR96Vh - This what it shows to me